# Fullscreen Playback glitched in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, fullscreen, windows-10-v1809

Whenever I try to play a video fullscreen in Chrome, from YouTube or any other site, my laptop crashes and shows a black screen for a while until I turn it off form the power button. In YouTube, green colored rectangles cover the video every 1-2 seconds.

PC Specs: 
Acer Aspire 3 
1920 x 1080 
Ryzen 5 2500u 
Display Drivers: Radeon Settings Version `2018.0126.1720.31188` 
GPU: Vega 8 (iGPU) 
Memory: 8 GB (Dual Channel) DDR4 1333 MHz (I'll try to see if I can increase the frequency of the RAM in the BIOS as the current frequencies are of DDR2 era) 
OS Version: Windows 10 Home 1809 
OS Build: 17763.316 
Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) 

I'm using Adblock Plus and Dark Reader Extensions, as well as Just Black theme (made by Google). 

Incident occurred both while charging and not charging.

Is it a problem related to the Ryzen CPU and AMD iGPU as there is another post that has a similar problem (in games) and the user has R3 2200g build.

Edit: The green rectangles appear in videos from other sites too 
Edit 2: Tried watching a video from the best Chrome Downloader, i.e., Microsoft Edge and the problem wasn't there 
Edit 3: Disabled Hardware Acceleration from Chrome and the problem was solved. I can't delete the post as the option is not there.

Answer (score 2):

[I FIGURED OUT THE WAY SO I AM ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION]

Disable Hardware Acceleration in Chrome settings.

Also, go to (Windows) Settings > System > Display > Display Settings and then remove chrome from the list (both classic app and universal app)